# jquery find next class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a foreach loop, i have several html blocks which look like this:

```
<label class="">Replace image/poster:</label>
<input type="file" name="replaced_main_image" class="form-control-file-border input-image-preview" />                   
                
<!-- preview replaced main image -->
<br />
<label class="">Preview replaced image/poster:</label><br />
<img class="image-preview" width="100" src="#" /> <!-- preview image -->
```

For a preview for the just choosen image to upload, i use this code:

```
// preview new selected image 
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.image-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }    
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
}
$(".input-image-preview").change(function() {
 readURL(this);

});
```

This works fine, but in this case, every img with class `img-preview` gets the source. And i want only the next img with class `img-preview`.

As far as i know, i have to change a line in the function and should look something like:

```
 reader.onload = function(e) {
      find next --> $('.image-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
```

I dont know what is the correct syntax for this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$(input).nextAll('.image-preview').eq( 0 ).attr('src', e.target.result);
```

use `input` as your source that you passed into the function then find all next `.image-preview` and limit it to first one with `.eq( 0 )`

Comment: `$('.image-preview:eq(2)')` does not show any preview at all